# light weight javascript text editor not working

Tags: javascript, text-editor

I have this light weight text editor that go on a webpage. It all displays well and work almost as expected but when you post the form the text area values do not get posted, I suspect the text is not inserted into the 'real' text box from the 'fake' textbox...

Here is the javascript and css and html. You will have to run this locally to output in php or something the $_POST values, to see what I mean.

```js
window.FontAwesomeKitConfig = {"asyncLoading":{"enabled":true},"autoA11y":{"enabled":true},"baseUrl":"https://ka-f.fontawesome.com","baseUrlKit":"https://kit.fontawesome.com","detectConflictsUntil":null,"iconUploads":{},"id":44475219,"license":"free","method":"css","minify":{"enabled":true},"token":"7ce56be44b","v4FontFaceShim":{"enabled":false},"v4shim":{"enabled":false},"version":"5.15.4"};
!function(t){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("kit-loader",t):t()}((function(){"use strict";function t(e){return(t="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&t.constructor===Symbol&&t!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof t})(e)}function e(t,e,n){return e in t?Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:n,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):t[e]=n,t}function n(t,e){var n=Object.keys(t);if(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols){var r=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(t);e&&(r=r.filter((function(e){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(t,e).enumerable}))),n.push.apply(n,r)}return n}function r(t){for(var r=1;r<arguments.length;r++){var o=null!=arguments[r]?arguments[r]:{};r%2?n(Object(o),!0).forEach((function(n){e(t,n,o[n])})):Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors?Object.defineProperties(t,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(o)):n(Object(o)).forEach((function(e){Object.defineProperty(t,e,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,e))}))}return t}function o(t,e){return function(t){if(Array.isArray(t))return t}(t)||function(t,e){if("undefined"==typeof Symbol||!(Symbol.iterator in Object(t)))return;var n=[],r=!0,o=!1,i=void 0;try{for(var c,a=t[Symbol.iterator]();!(r=(c=a.next()).done)&&(n.push(c.value),!e||n.length!==e);r=!0);}catch(t){o=!0,i=t}finally{try{r||null==a.return||a.return()}finally{if(o)throw i}}return n}(t,e)||function(t,e){if(!t)return;if("string"==typeof t)return i(t,e);var n=Object.prototype.toString.call(t).slice(8,-1);"Object"===n&&t.constructor&&(n=t.constructor.name);if("Map"===n||"Set"===n)return Array.from(t);if("Arguments"===n||/^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n))return i(t,e)}(t,e)||function(){throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.")}()}function i(t,e){(null==e||e>t.length)&&(e=t.length);for(var n=0,r=new Array(e);n<e;n++)r[n]=t[n];return r}function c(t,e){var n=e&&e.addOn||"",r=e&&e.baseFilename||t.license+n,o=e&&e.minify?".min":"",i=e&&e.fileSuffix||t.method,c=e&&e.subdir||t.method;return t.baseUrl+"/releases/"+("latest"===t.version?"latest":"v".concat(t.version))+"/"+c+"/"+r+o+"."+i}function a(t){return t.baseUrlKit+"/"+t.token+"/"+t.id+"/kit-upload.css"}function u(t,e){var n=e||["fa"],r="."+Array.prototype.join.call(n,",."),o=t.querySelectorAll(r);Array.prototype.forEach.call(o,(function(e){var n=e.getAttribute("title");e.setAttribute("aria-hidden","true");var r=!e.nextElementSibling||!e.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("sr-only");if(n&&r){var o=t.createElement("span");o.innerHTML=n,o.classList.add("sr-only"),e.parentNode.insertBefore(o,e.nextSibling)}}))}var f,s=function(){},d="undefined"!=typeof global&&void 0!==global.process&&"function"==typeof global.process.emit,l="undefined"==typeof setImmediate?setTimeout:setImmediate,h=[];function m(){for(var t=0;t<h.length;t++)h[t][0](h[t][1]);h=[],f=!1}function p(t,e){h.push([t,e]),f||(f=!0,l(m,0))}function y(t){var e=t.owner,n=e._state,r=e._data,o=t[n],i=t.then;if("function"==typeof o){n="fulfilled";try{r=o(r)}catch(t){w(i,t)}}b(i,r)||("fulfilled"===n&&v(i,r),"rejected"===n&&w(i,r))}function b(e,n){var r;try{if(e===n)throw new TypeError("A promises callback cannot return that same promise.");if(n&&("function"==typeof n||"object"===t(n))){var o=n.then;if("function"==typeof o)return o.call(n,(function(t){r||(r=!0,n===t?g(e,t):v(e,t))}),(function(t){r||(r=!0,w(e,t))})),!0}}catch(t){return r||w(e,t),!0}return!1}function v(t,e){t!==e&&b(t,e)||g(t,e)}function g(t,e){"pending"===t._state&&(t._state="settled",t._data=e,p(S,t))}function w(t,e){"pending"===t._state&&(t._state="settled",t._data=e,p(O,t))}function A(t){t._then=t._then.forEach(y)}function S(t){t._state="fulfilled",A(t)}function O(t){t._state="rejected",A(t),!t._handled&&d&&global.process.emit("unhandledRejection",t._data,t)}function j(t){global.process.emit("rejectionHandled",t)}function E(t){if("function"!=typeof t)throw new TypeError("Promise resolver "+t+" is not a function");if(this instanceof E==!1)throw new TypeError("Failed to construct 'Promise': Please use the 'new' operator, this object constructor cannot be called as a function.");this._then=[],function(t,e){function n(t){w(e,t)}try{t((function(t){v(e,t)}),n)}catch(t){n(t)}}(t,this)}E.prototype={constructor:E,_state:"pending",_then:null,_data:void 0,_handled:!1,then:function(t,e){var n={owner:this,then:new this.constructor(s),fulfilled:t,rejected:e};return!e&&!t||this._handled||(this._handled=!0,"rejected"===this._state&&d&&p(j,this)),"fulfilled"===this._state||"rejected"===this._state?p(y,n):this._then.push(n),n.then},catch:function(t){return this.then(null,t)}},E.all=function(t){if(!Array.isArray(t))throw new TypeError("You must pass an array to Promise.all().");return new E((function(e,n){var r=[],o=0;function i(t){return o++,function(n){r[t]=n,--o||e(r)}}for(var c,a=0;a<t.length;a++)(c=t[a])&&"function"==typeof c.then?c.then(i(a),n):r[a]=c;o||e(r)}))},E.race=function(t){if(!Array.isArray(t))throw new TypeError("You must pass an array to Promise.race().");return new E((function(e,n){for(var r,o=0;o<t.length;o++)(r=t[o])&&"function"==typeof r.then?r.then(e,n):e(r)}))},E.resolve=function(e){return e&&"object"===t(e)&&e.constructor===E?e:new E((function(t){t(e)}))},E.reject=function(t){return new E((function(e,n){n(t)}))};var _="function"==typeof Promise?Promise:E;function P(t,e){var n=e.fetch,r=e.XMLHttpRequest,o=e.token,i=t;return"URLSearchParams"in window?(i=new URL(t)).searchParams.set("token",o):i=i+"?token="+encodeURIComponent(o),i=i.toString(),new _((function(t,e){if("function"==typeof n)n(i,{mode:"cors",cache:"default"}).then((function(t){if(t.ok)return t.text();throw new Error("")})).then((function(e){t(e)})).catch(e);else if("function"==typeof r){var o=new r;o.addEventListener("loadend",(function(){this.responseText?t(this.responseText):e(new Error(""))}));["abort","error","timeout"].map((function(t){o.addEventListener(t,(function(){e(new Error(""))}))})),o.open("GET",i),o.send()}else{e(new Error(""))}}))}function C(t,e,n){var r=t;return[[/(url\("?)\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\./g,function(t,n){return"".concat(n).concat(e)}],[/(url\("?)\.\.\/webfonts/g,function(t,r){return"".concat(r).concat(e,"/releases/v").concat(n,"/webfonts")}],[/(url\("?)https:\/\/kit-free([^.])*\.fontawesome\.com/g,function(t,n){return"".concat(n).concat(e)}]].forEach((function(t){var e=o(t,2),n=e[0],i=e[1];r=r.replace(n,i)})),r}function F(t,e){var n=arguments.length>2&&void 0!==arguments[2]?arguments[2]:function(){},o=e.document||o,i=u.bind(u,o,["fa","fab","fas","far","fal","fad","fak"]),f=Object.keys(t.iconUploads||{}).length>0;t.autoA11y.enabled&&n(i);var s=[{id:"fa-main",addOn:void 0}];t.v4shim.enabled&&s.push({id:"fa-v4-shims",addOn:"-v4-shims"}),t.v4FontFaceShim.enabled&&s.push({id:"fa-v4-font-face",addOn:"-v4-font-face"}),f&&s.push({id:"fa-kit-upload",customCss:!0});var d=s.map((function(n){return new _((function(o,i){P(n.customCss?a(t):c(t,{addOn:n.addOn,minify:t.minify.enabled}),e).then((function(i){o(U(i,r(r({},e),{},{baseUrl:t.baseUrl,version:t.version,id:n.id,contentFilter:function(t,e){return C(t,e.baseUrl,e.version)}})))})).catch(i)}))}));return _.all(d)}function U(t,e){var n=e.contentFilter||function(t,e){return t},r=document.createElement("style"),o=document.createTextNode(n(t,e));return r.appendChild(o),r.media="all",e.id&&r.setAttribute("id",e.id),e&&e.detectingConflicts&&e.detectionIgnoreAttr&&r.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute(e.detectionIgnoreAttr)),r}function k(t,e){e.autoA11y=t.autoA11y.enabled,"pro"===t.license&&(e.autoFetchSvg=!0,e.fetchSvgFrom=t.baseUrl+"/releases/"+("latest"===t.version?"latest":"v".concat(t.version))+"/svgs",e.fetchUploadedSvgFrom=t.uploadsUrl);var n=[];return t.v4shim.enabled&&n.push(new _((function(n,o){P(c(t,{addOn:"-v4-shims",minify:t.minify.enabled}),e).then((function(t){n(I(t,r(r({},e),{},{id:"fa-v4-shims"})))})).catch(o)}))),n.push(new _((function(n,o){P(c(t,{minify:t.minify.enabled}),e).then((function(t){var o=I(t,r(r({},e),{},{id:"fa-main"}));n(function(t,e){var n=e&&void 0!==e.autoFetchSvg?e.autoFetchSvg:void 0,r=e&&void 0!==e.autoA11y?e.autoA11y:void 0;void 0!==r&&t.setAttribute("data-auto-a11y",r?"true":"false");n&&(t.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute("data-auto-fetch-svg")),t.setAttribute("data-fetch-svg-from",e.fetchSvgFrom),t.setAttribute("data-fetch-uploaded-svg-from",e.fetchUploadedSvgFrom));return t}(o,e))})).catch(o)}))),_.all(n)}function I(t,e){var n=document.createElement("SCRIPT"),r=document.createTextNode(t);return n.appendChild(r),n.referrerPolicy="strict-origin",e.id&&n.setAttribute("id",e.id),e&&e.detectingConflicts&&e.detectionIgnoreAttr&&n.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute(e.detectionIgnoreAttr)),n}function L(t){var e,n=[],r=document,o=r.documentElement.doScroll,i=(o?/^loaded|^c/:/^loaded|^i|^c/).test(r.readyState);i||r.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",e=function(){for(r.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",e),i=1;e=n.shift();)e()}),i?setTimeout(t,0):n.push(t)}function T(t){"undefined"!=typeof MutationObserver&&new MutationObserver(t).observe(document,{childList:!0,subtree:!0})}try{if(window.FontAwesomeKitConfig){var x=window.FontAwesomeKitConfig,M={detectingConflicts:x.detectConflictsUntil&&new Date<=new Date(x.detectConflictsUntil),detectionIgnoreAttr:"data-fa-detection-ignore",fetch:window.fetch,token:x.token,XMLHttpRequest:window.XMLHttpRequest,document:document},D=document.currentScript,N=D?D.parentElement:document.head;(function(){var t=arguments.length>0&&void 0!==arguments[0]?arguments[0]:{},e=arguments.length>1&&void 0!==arguments[1]?arguments[1]:{};return"js"===t.method?k(t,e):"css"===t.method?F(t,e,(function(t){L(t),T(t)})):void 0})(x,M).then((function(t){t.map((function(t){try{N.insertBefore(t,D?D.nextSibling:null)}catch(e){N.appendChild(t)}})),M.detectingConflicts&&D&&L((function(){D.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute(M.detectionIgnoreAttr));var t=function(t,e){var n=document.createElement("script");return e&&e.detectionIgnoreAttr&&n.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute(e.detectionIgnoreAttr)),n.src=c(t,{baseFilename:"conflict-detection",fileSuffix:"js",subdir:"js",minify:t.minify.enabled}),n}(x,M);document.body.appendChild(t)}))})).catch((function(t){console.error("".concat("Font Awesome Kit:"," ").concat(t))}))}}catch(t){console.error("".concat("Font Awesome Kit:"," ").concat(t))}}));
//internal variables


var show = false;

//textAreaSelector
const textAreaSelector = document.getElementById('text-editor');

//buttonsToolbar
var buttonsToolbar = document.createElement('div');
buttonsToolbar.setAttribute('id', 'buttonsToolbar');
///buttonsToolbar

//textEditor
var textEditor = document.createElement('div');
textEditor.setAttribute('id', 'textEditor');
textEditor.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
///textEditor

insidetext = document.getElementById('text-editor').textContent;

textEditor.innerHTML = insidetext;


//functions
function insertAfter(insertObject) {
  insertObject.forEach(insertObj => {
    insertObj.reference.parentNode.insertBefore(insertObj.new, insertObj.reference.nextSibling);
  });
}

var buttons = [
  {
    name: 'alignLeft',
    cmd: 'justifyLeft',
    icon: 'fas fa-align-left'
  },
  {
    name: 'alignCenter',
    cmd: 'justifyCenter',
    icon: 'fas fa-align-center'
  },
  {
    name: 'alignJustify',
    cmd: 'justifyFull',
    icon: 'fas fa-align-justify'
  },
  {
    name: 'alignRight',
    cmd: 'justifyRight',
    icon: 'fas fa-align-right'
  },
  {
    name: 'bold',
    cmd: 'bold',
    icon: 'fas fa-bold'
  },
  {
    name: 'italic',
    cmd: 'italic',
    icon: 'fas fa-italic'
  },
  {
    name: 'underline',
    cmd: 'underline',
    icon: 'fas fa-underline'
  },
  {
    name: 'insertOrderedList',
    cmd: 'insertOrderedList',
    icon: 'fas fa-list-ol'
  },
  {
    name: 'insertUnorderedList',
    cmd: 'insertUnorderedList',
    icon: 'fas fa-list-ul'
  },
  
 // {
 //   name: 'insertImage',
 //   cmd: 'insertImage',
//    icon: 'fas fa-image'
 // },
 // {
  //  name: 'insertLink',
  //  cmd: 'createLink',
  //  icon: 'fas fa-link'
 // },
  {
    name: 'showCode',
    cmd: 'showCode',
    icon: 'fas fa-code'
  },
]

buttons.forEach(button => {
  //buttonElement
  let buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
  buttonElement.type = 'button';
  buttonElement.setAttribute('id', button.name);
  ///buttonElement

  //buttonIcon
  let buttonIcon = document.createElement('i');
  buttonIcon.setAttribute('class', button.icon);
  ///buttonIcon

  buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].classList.remove('active');
    }

    buttonElement.classList.add('active');

    switch (button.cmd) {
      case 'insertImage':
        url = prompt('Enter image link here: ', '');
        if (url) {
          document.execCommand(button.cmd, false, url);
        }

        const images = textEditor.querySelectorAll('img');

        images.forEach(img => {
          img.style.maxWidth = '500px';
        });
        break;
      
    //  case 'createLink':
    //    url = prompt('Enter URL link here: ', '');
    //    text = prompt('Enter link text here: ', '');
    //    if (url && text) {
    //      document.execCommand(
    //        'insertHTML',
    //        false,
    //        `<a href=${url} target='_blank'>${text}</a>`
    //      );
    //    }

        const links = textEditor.querySelectorAll('a');

        links.forEach(lnk => {
          lnk.target = '_blank';

          lnk.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            textEditor.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'false');
          });

          lnk.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            textEditor.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
          });
        });
        break;
      
      case 'showCode':
        if (show) {
          buttonElement.classList.remove('active');
          textEditor.innerHTML = textEditor.textContent;
          show = false;
        } else {
          textEditor.textContent = textEditor.innerHTML;
          show = true;
        }
        break;
    
      default:
        document.execCommand(button.cmd, false, null);
        break;
    }
  });

  buttonElement.appendChild(buttonIcon);
  buttonsToolbar.appendChild(buttonElement);
});

insertAfter([
  {
    reference: textAreaSelector,
    new: textEditor
  },
  {
    reference: textAreaSelector,
    new: buttonsToolbar
  }
]);


textAreaSelector.remove();
```

```css
#buttonsToolbar button:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

#buttonsToolbar button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

  margin: 0 5px 0 0;

  border: none;
  outline: none;

  cursor: pointer;
}

#buttonsToolbar {
  width: fit-content;
}

#textEditor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;

  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#buttonsToolbar button.active {
  background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214)
}

#textEditor p {
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="input textarea">    
 <label for="address">Address (200 characters)</label>
<textarea name="businessaddress" id="text-editor" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary float-end" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some points you were missing:
You need the `<textarea>` element since an **editable div is not a proper form** element (so you won't get any $_POST data).
Therefore you need to delete
`textAreaSelector.remove();` – but you can just hide it via e.g a `display:none;`

Besides, you will also need to **synchronize current text inputs between editor div and textarea**:

```
textEditor.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  let currentContent = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
  textAreaSelector.value = currentContent;
})
```

#### Edit: editor updating on button click

```js
//internal variables
var show = false;

//textAreaSelector
const textAreaSelector = document.getElementById("text-editor");

//buttonsToolbar
var buttonsToolbar = document.createElement("div");
buttonsToolbar.setAttribute("id", "buttonsToolbar");

var textEditor = document.createElement("div");
textEditor.setAttribute("id", "textEditor");
textEditor.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
insidetext = textAreaSelector.textContent;
textEditor.innerHTML = insidetext;

textEditor.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  updateText()
});

// update/synchronize and sanitize text
function updateText() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let currentContent = textEditor.innerHTML;
    let currentContentTxt = textEditor.textContent.replaceAll(/\s/g, '');
    currentContent = currentContent.replaceAll('<div>', '<p>').
    replaceAll('</div>', '</p>').
    replaceAll('<i>', '<em>').
    replaceAll('</i>', '</em>').
    replaceAll('<b>', '<strong>').
    replaceAll('</b>', '</strong>').
    replaceAll('<div style=', '<p style=').
    replaceAll('</div>', '</p>');

    // remove empty html elements 
    if (!currentContentTxt) {
      currentContent = '';
    }
    textAreaSelector.value = currentContent;
    //console.log(currentContent);
    //console.log(currentContentTxt);
  }, 200);

}


//functions
function insertAfter(insertObject) {
  insertObject.forEach((insertObj) => {
    insertObj.reference.parentNode.insertBefore(
      insertObj.new,
      insertObj.reference.nextSibling
    );
  });
}

var buttons = [{
    name: "alignLeft",
    cmd: "justifyLeft",
    icon: "fas fa-align-left"
  },
  {
    name: "alignCenter",
    cmd: "justifyCenter",
    icon: "fas fa-align-center"
  },
  {
    name: "alignJustify",
    cmd: "justifyFull",
    icon: "fas fa-align-justify"
  },
  {
    name: "alignRight",
    cmd: "justifyRight",
    icon: "fas fa-align-right"
  },
  {
    name: "bold",
    cmd: "bold",
    icon: "fas fa-bold"
  },
  {
    name: "italic",
    cmd: "italic",
    icon: "fas fa-italic"
  },
  {
    name: "underline",
    cmd: "underline",
    icon: "fas fa-underline"
  },
  {
    name: "insertOrderedList",
    cmd: "insertOrderedList",
    icon: "fas fa-list-ol"
  },
  {
    name: "insertUnorderedList",
    cmd: "insertUnorderedList",
    icon: "fas fa-list-ul"
  },

  // {
  //   name: 'insertImage',
  //   cmd: 'insertImage',
  //    icon: 'fas fa-image'
  // },
  // {
  //  name: 'insertLink',
  //  cmd: 'createLink',
  //  icon: 'fas fa-link'
  // },
  {
    name: "showCode",
    cmd: "showCode",
    icon: "fas fa-code"
  }
];

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  //buttonElement
  let buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
  buttonElement.type = "button";
  buttonElement.setAttribute("id", button.name);
  ///buttonElement

  //buttonIcon
  let buttonIcon = document.createElement("i");
  buttonIcon.setAttribute("class", button.icon);
  ///buttonIcon

  buttonElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].classList.remove("active");
    }

    buttonElement.classList.add("active");
    updateText();


    switch (button.cmd) {
      case "insertImage":
        url = prompt("Enter image link here: ", "");
        if (url) {
          document.execCommand(button.cmd, false, url);
        }

        const images = textEditor.querySelectorAll("img");

        images.forEach((img) => {
          img.style.maxWidth = "500px";
        });
        break;

        //  case 'createLink':
        //    url = prompt('Enter URL link here: ', '');
        //    text = prompt('Enter link text here: ', '');
        //    if (url && text) {
        //      document.execCommand(
        //        'insertHTML',
        //        false,
        //        `<a href=${url} target='_blank'>${text}</a>`
        //      );
        //    }

        const links = textEditor.querySelectorAll("a");

        links.forEach((lnk) => {
          lnk.target = "_blank";

          lnk.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            textEditor.setAttribute("contentEditable", "false");
          });

          lnk.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
            textEditor.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
          });
        });
        break;

      case "showCode":
        if (show) {
          buttonElement.classList.remove("active");
          textEditor.innerHTML = textEditor.textContent;
          show = false;
        } else {
          textEditor.textContent = textEditor.innerHTML;
          show = true;
        }
        break;

      default:
        document.execCommand(button.cmd, false, null);
        break;


    }
  });

  buttonElement.appendChild(buttonIcon);
  buttonsToolbar.appendChild(buttonElement);
});

insertAfter([{
    reference: textAreaSelector,
    new: textEditor
  },
  {
    reference: textAreaSelector,
    new: buttonsToolbar
  }
]);

//textAreaSelector.remove();


window.FontAwesomeKitConfig = {
  asyncLoading: {
    enabled: true
  },
  autoA11y: {
    enabled: true
  },
  baseUrl: "https://ka-f.fontawesome.com",
  baseUrlKit: "https://kit.fontawesome.com",
  detectConflictsUntil: null,
  iconUploads: {},
  id: 44475219,
  license: "free",
  method: "css",
  minify: {
    enabled: true
  },
  token: "7ce56be44b",
  v4FontFaceShim: {
    enabled: false
  },
  v4shim: {
    enabled: false
  },
  version: "5.15.4"
};
!(function(t) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("kit-loader", t) : t();
})(function() {
  "use strict";

  function t(e) {
    return (t =
      "function" == typeof Symbol && "symbol" == typeof Symbol.iterator ?
      function(t) {
        return typeof t;
      } :
      function(t) {
        return t &&
          "function" == typeof Symbol &&
          t.constructor === Symbol &&
          t !== Symbol.prototype ?
          "symbol" :
          typeof t;
      })(e);
  }

  function e(t, e, n) {
    return (
      e in t ?
      Object.defineProperty(t, e, {
        value: n,
        enumerable: !0,
        configurable: !0,
        writable: !0
      }) :
      (t[e] = n),
      t
    );
  }

  function n(t, e) {
    var n = Object.keys(t);
    if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) {
      var r = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(t);
      e &&
        (r = r.filter(function(e) {
          return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(t, e).enumerable;
        })),
        n.push.apply(n, r);
    }
    return n;
  }

  function r(t) {
    for (var r = 1; r < arguments.length; r++) {
      var o = null != arguments[r] ? arguments[r] : {};
      r % 2 ?
        n(Object(o), !0).forEach(function(n) {
          e(t, n, o[n]);
        }) :
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors ?
        Object.defineProperties(t, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(o)) :
        n(Object(o)).forEach(function(e) {
          Object.defineProperty(t, e, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, e));
        });
    }
    return t;
  }

  function o(t, e) {
    return (
      (function(t) {
        if (Array.isArray(t)) return t;
      })(t) ||
      (function(t, e) {
        if ("undefined" == typeof Symbol || !(Symbol.iterator in Object(t)))
          return;
        var n = [],
          r = !0,
          o = !1,
          i = void 0;
        try {
          for (
            var c, a = t[Symbol.iterator](); !(r = (c = a.next()).done) &&
            (n.push(c.value), !e || n.length !== e); r = !0
          );
        } catch (t) {
          (o = !0), (i = t);
        } finally {
          try {
            r || null == a.return || a.return();
          } finally {
            if (o) throw i;
          }
        }
        return n;
      })(t, e) ||
      (function(t, e) {
        if (!t) return;
        if ("string" == typeof t) return i(t, e);
        var n = Object.prototype.toString.call(t).slice(8, -1);
        "Object" === n && t.constructor && (n = t.constructor.name);
        if ("Map" === n || "Set" === n) return Array.from(t);
        if (
          "Arguments" === n ||
          /^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n)
        )
          return i(t, e);
      })(t, e) ||
      (function() {
        throw new TypeError(
          "Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."
        );
      })()
    );
  }

  function i(t, e) {
    (null == e || e > t.length) && (e = t.length);
    for (var n = 0, r = new Array(e); n < e; n++) r[n] = t[n];
    return r;
  }

  function c(t, e) {
    var n = (e && e.addOn) || "",
      r = (e && e.baseFilename) || t.license + n,
      o = e && e.minify ? ".min" : "",
      i = (e && e.fileSuffix) || t.method,
      c = (e && e.subdir) || t.method;
    return (
      t.baseUrl +
      "/releases/" +
      ("latest" === t.version ? "latest" : "v".concat(t.version)) +
      "/" +
      c +
      "/" +
      r +
      o +
      "." +
      i
    );
  }

  function a(t) {
    return t.baseUrlKit + "/" + t.token + "/" + t.id + "/kit-upload.css";
  }

  function u(t, e) {
    var n = e || ["fa"],
      r = "." + Array.prototype.join.call(n, ",."),
      o = t.querySelectorAll(r);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(o, function(e) {
      var n = e.getAttribute("title");
      e.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
      var r = !e.nextElementSibling ||
        !e.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("sr-only");
      if (n && r) {
        var o = t.createElement("span");
        (o.innerHTML = n),
        o.classList.add("sr-only"),
          e.parentNode.insertBefore(o, e.nextSibling);
      }
    });
  }
  var f,
    s = function() {},
    d =
    "undefined" != typeof global &&
    void 0 !== global.process &&
    "function" == typeof global.process.emit,
    l = "undefined" == typeof setImmediate ? setTimeout : setImmediate,
    h = [];

  function m() {
    for (var t = 0; t < h.length; t++) h[t][0](h[t][1]);
    (h = []), (f = !1);
  }

  function p(t, e) {
    h.push([t, e]), f || ((f = !0), l(m, 0));
  }

  function y(t) {
    var e = t.owner,
      n = e._state,
      r = e._data,
      o = t[n],
      i = t.then;
    if ("function" == typeof o) {
      n = "fulfilled";
      try {
        r = o(r);
      } catch (t) {
        w(i, t);
      }
    }
    b(i, r) || ("fulfilled" === n && v(i, r), "rejected" === n && w(i, r));
  }

  function b(e, n) {
    var r;
    try {
      if (e === n)
        throw new TypeError(
          "A promises callback cannot return that same promise."
        );
      if (n && ("function" == typeof n || "object" === t(n))) {
        var o = n.then;
        if ("function" == typeof o)
          return (
            o.call(
              n,
              function(t) {
                r || ((r = !0), n === t ? g(e, t) : v(e, t));
              },
              function(t) {
                r || ((r = !0), w(e, t));
              }
            ), !0
          );
      }
    } catch (t) {
      return r || w(e, t), !0;
    }
    return !1;
  }

  function v(t, e) {
    (t !== e && b(t, e)) || g(t, e);
  }

  function g(t, e) {
    "pending" === t._state && ((t._state = "settled"), (t._data = e), p(S, t));
  }

  function w(t, e) {
    "pending" === t._state && ((t._state = "settled"), (t._data = e), p(O, t));
  }

  function A(t) {
    t._then = t._then.forEach(y);
  }

  function S(t) {
    (t._state = "fulfilled"), A(t);
  }

  function O(t) {
    (t._state = "rejected"),
    A(t), !t._handled && d && global.process.emit("unhandledRejection", t._data, t);
  }

  function j(t) {
    global.process.emit("rejectionHandled", t);
  }

  function E(t) {
    if ("function" != typeof t)
      throw new TypeError("Promise resolver " + t + " is not a function");
    if (this instanceof E == !1)
      throw new TypeError(
        "Failed to construct 'Promise': Please use the 'new' operator, this object constructor cannot be called as a function."
      );
    (this._then = []),
    (function(t, e) {
      function n(t) {
        w(e, t);
      }
      try {
        t(function(t) {
          v(e, t);
        }, n);
      } catch (t) {
        n(t);
      }
    })(t, this);
  }
  (E.prototype = {
    constructor: E,
    _state: "pending",
    _then: null,
    _data: void 0,
    _handled: !1,
    then: function(t, e) {
      var n = {
        owner: this,
        then: new this.constructor(s),
        fulfilled: t,
        rejected: e
      };
      return (
        (!e && !t) ||
        this._handled ||
        ((this._handled = !0), "rejected" === this._state && d && p(j, this)),
        "fulfilled" === this._state || "rejected" === this._state ?
        p(y, n) :
        this._then.push(n),
        n.then
      );
    },
    catch: function(t) {
      return this.then(null, t);
    }
  }),
  (E.all = function(t) {
    if (!Array.isArray(t))
      throw new TypeError("You must pass an array to Promise.all().");
    return new E(function(e, n) {
      var r = [],
        o = 0;

      function i(t) {
        return (
          o++,
          function(n) {
            (r[t] = n), --o || e(r);
          }
        );
      }
      for (var c, a = 0; a < t.length; a++)
        (c = t[a]) && "function" == typeof c.then ?
        c.then(i(a), n) :
        (r[a] = c);
      o || e(r);
    });
  }),
  (E.race = function(t) {
    if (!Array.isArray(t))
      throw new TypeError("You must pass an array to Promise.race().");
    return new E(function(e, n) {
      for (var r, o = 0; o < t.length; o++)
        (r = t[o]) && "function" == typeof r.then ? r.then(e, n) : e(r);
    });
  }),
  (E.resolve = function(e) {
    return e && "object" === t(e) && e.constructor === E ?
      e :
      new E(function(t) {
        t(e);
      });
  }),
  (E.reject = function(t) {
    return new E(function(e, n) {
      n(t);
    });
  });
  var _ = "function" == typeof Promise ? Promise : E;

  function P(t, e) {
    var n = e.fetch,
      r = e.XMLHttpRequest,
      o = e.token,
      i = t;
    return (
      "URLSearchParams" in window ?
      (i = new URL(t)).searchParams.set("token", o) :
      (i = i + "?token=" + encodeURIComponent(o)),
      (i = i.toString()),
      new _(function(t, e) {
        if ("function" == typeof n)
          n(i, {
            mode: "cors",
            cache: "default"
          })
          .then(function(t) {
            if (t.ok) return t.text();
            throw new Error("");
          })
          .then(function(e) {
            t(e);
          })
          .catch(e);
        else if ("function" == typeof r) {
          var o = new r();
          o.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
            this.responseText ? t(this.responseText) : e(new Error(""));
          });
          ["abort", "error", "timeout"].map(function(t) {
              o.addEventListener(t, function() {
                e(new Error(""));
              });
            }),
            o.open("GET", i),
            o.send();
        } else {
          e(new Error(""));
        }
      })
    );
  }

  function C(t, e, n) {
    var r = t;
    return (
      [
        [
          /(url\("?)\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\./g,
          function(t, n) {
            return "".concat(n).concat(e);
          }
        ],
        [
          /(url\("?)\.\.\/webfonts/g,
          function(t, r) {
            return "".concat(r).concat(e, "/releases/v").concat(n, "/webfonts");
          }
        ],
        [
          /(url\("?)https:\/\/kit-free([^.])*\.fontawesome\.com/g,
          function(t, n) {
            return "".concat(n).concat(e);
          }
        ]
      ].forEach(function(t) {
        var e = o(t, 2),
          n = e[0],
          i = e[1];
        r = r.replace(n, i);
      }),
      r
    );
  }

  function F(t, e) {
    var n =
      arguments.length > 2 && void 0 !== arguments[2] ?
      arguments[2] :
      function() {},
      o = e.document || o,
      i = u.bind(u, o, ["fa", "fab", "fas", "far", "fal", "fad", "fak"]),
      f = Object.keys(t.iconUploads || {}).length > 0;
    t.autoA11y.enabled && n(i);
    var s = [{
      id: "fa-main",
      addOn: void 0
    }];
    t.v4shim.enabled && s.push({
        id: "fa-v4-shims",
        addOn: "-v4-shims"
      }),
      t.v4FontFaceShim.enabled &&
      s.push({
        id: "fa-v4-font-face",
        addOn: "-v4-font-face"
      }),
      f && s.push({
        id: "fa-kit-upload",
        customCss: !0
      });
    var d = s.map(function(n) {
      return new _(function(o, i) {
        P(
            n.customCss ?
            a(t) :
            c(t, {
              addOn: n.addOn,
              minify: t.minify.enabled
            }),
            e
          )
          .then(function(i) {
            o(
              U(
                i,
                r(
                  r({}, e), {}, {
                    baseUrl: t.baseUrl,
                    version: t.version,
                    id: n.id,
                    contentFilter: function(t, e) {
                      return C(t, e.baseUrl, e.version);
                    }
                  }
                )
              )
            );
          })
          .catch(i);
      });
    });
    return _.all(d);
  }

  function U(t, e) {
    var n =
      e.contentFilter ||
      function(t, e) {
        return t;
      },
      r = document.createElement("style"),
      o = document.createTextNode(n(t, e));
    return (
      r.appendChild(o),
      (r.media = "all"),
      e.id && r.setAttribute("id", e.id),
      e &&
      e.detectingConflicts &&
      e.detectionIgnoreAttr &&
      r.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute(e.detectionIgnoreAttr)),
      r
    );
  }

  function k(t, e) {
    (e.autoA11y = t.autoA11y.enabled),
    "pro" === t.license &&
      ((e.autoFetchSvg = !0),
        (e.fetchSvgFrom =
          t.baseUrl +
          "/releases/" +
          ("latest" === t.version ? "latest" : "v".concat(t.version)) +
          "/svgs"),
        (e.fetchUploadedSvgFrom = t.uploadsUrl));
    var n = [];
    return (
      t.v4shim.enabled &&
      n.push(
        new _(function(n, o) {
          P(c(t, {
              addOn: "-v4-shims",
              minify: t.minify.enabled
            }), e)
            .then(function(t) {
              n(I(t, r(r({}, e), {}, {
                id: "fa-v4-shims"
              })));
            })
            .catch(o);
        })
      ),
      n.push(
        new _(function(n, o) {
          P(c(t, {
              minify: t.minify.enabled
            }), e)
            .then(function(t) {
              var o = I(t, r(r({}, e), {}, {
                id: "fa-main"
              }));
              n(
                (function(t, e) {
                  var n =
                    e && void 0 !== e.autoFetchSvg ? e.autoFetchSvg : void 0,
                    r = e && void 0 !== e.autoA11y ? e.autoA11y : void 0;
                  void 0 !== r &&
                    t.setAttribute("data-auto-a11y", r ? "true" : "false");
                  n &&
                    (t.setAttributeNode(
                        document.createAttribute("data-auto-fetch-svg")
                      ),
                      t.setAttribute("data-fetch-svg-from", e.fetchSvgFrom),
                      t.setAttribute(
                        "data-fetch-uploaded-svg-from",
                        e.fetchUploadedSvgFrom
                      ));
                  return t;
                })(o, e)
              );
            })
            .catch(o);
        })
      ),
      _.all(n)
    );
  }

  function I(t, e) {
    var n = document.createElement("SCRIPT"),
      r = document.createTextNode(t);
    return (
      n.appendChild(r),
      (n.referrerPolicy = "strict-origin"),
      e.id && n.setAttribute("id", e.id),
      e &&
      e.detectingConflicts &&
      e.detectionIgnoreAttr &&
      n.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute(e.detectionIgnoreAttr)),
      n
    );
  }

  function L(t) {
    var e,
      n = [],
      r = document,
      o = r.documentElement.doScroll,
      i = (o ? /^loaded|^c/ : /^loaded|^i|^c/).test(r.readyState);
    i ||
      r.addEventListener(
        "DOMContentLoaded",
        (e = function() {
          for (
            r.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e), i = 1;
            (e = n.shift());

          )
            e();
        })
      ),
      i ? setTimeout(t, 0) : n.push(t);
  }

  function T(t) {
    "undefined" != typeof MutationObserver &&
      new MutationObserver(t).observe(document, {
        childList: !0,
        subtree: !0
      });
  }
  try {
    if (window.FontAwesomeKitConfig) {
      var x = window.FontAwesomeKitConfig,
        M = {
          detectingConflicts: x.detectConflictsUntil &&
            new Date() <= new Date(x.detectConflictsUntil),
          detectionIgnoreAttr: "data-fa-detection-ignore",
          fetch: window.fetch,
          token: x.token,
          XMLHttpRequest: window.XMLHttpRequest,
          document: document
        },
        D = document.currentScript,
        N = D ? D.parentElement : document.head;
      (function() {
        var t =
          arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : {},
          e =
          arguments.length > 1 && void 0 !== arguments[1] ? arguments[1] : {};
        return "js" === t.method ?
          k(t, e) :
          "css" === t.method ?
          F(t, e, function(t) {
            L(t), T(t);
          }) :
          void 0;
      })(x, M)
      .then(function(t) {
          t.map(function(t) {
              try {
                N.insertBefore(t, D ? D.nextSibling : null);
              } catch (e) {
                N.appendChild(t);
              }
            }),
            M.detectingConflicts &&
            D &&
            L(function() {
              D.setAttributeNode(
                document.createAttribute(M.detectionIgnoreAttr)
              );
              var t = (function(t, e) {
                var n = document.createElement("script");
                return (
                  e &&
                  e.detectionIgnoreAttr &&
                  n.setAttributeNode(
                    document.createAttribute(e.detectionIgnoreAttr)
                  ),
                  (n.src = c(t, {
                    baseFilename: "conflict-detection",
                    fileSuffix: "js",
                    subdir: "js",
                    minify: t.minify.enabled
                  })),
                  n
                );
              })(x, M);
              document.body.appendChild(t);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(t) {
          console.error("".concat("Font Awesome Kit:", " ").concat(t));
        });
    }
  } catch (t) {
    console.error("".concat("Font Awesome Kit:", " ").concat(t));
  }
});
```

```css
#buttonsToolbar button:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

#buttonsToolbar button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#buttonsToolbar {
  width: fit-content;
}

#textEditor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#buttonsToolbar button.active {
  background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214)
}

#textEditor p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div class="input textarea">
    <label for="address">Address (200 characters)</label>
    <textarea name="businessaddress" id="text-editor" rows="2"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary float-end" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### Better opt in for a more advanced rich text editor

The problem with most lightweight editors like this hey are lacking a lot of useful if not indispensable features like sanitizing pasteboard formating.

So I strongly recommend searching for other alternatives.
[Awesome WYSIWYG – A curated list of awesome WYSIWYG editors.](https://github.com/JefMari/awesome-wysiwyg)

Comment: Hi thank you soo much for this! atleast it is posting the values now. But just tested it. If you can make a text BOLD for instance, and save it, it does not keep that style change. I was hoping to use this as it is light weight unlike ckeditor.. would be great if someone can  fix it.. I am not a javascript dev..thank so much for thus far !

Comment: @gabrielkolbe: just updated the snippet. But honestly: better use a more advanced editor lib. My personal recommendation is [trumbowyg](https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg). It still depends on jquery but should be far more lightweight than behemoths like tinymce or ckeditor.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. Some the input text fields I need almost no styling just the line breaks, so I used mysqlescapestring to get the /r/n and replaced it server side with <BR>.. which seemed to do the trick for now. thanks so much for your help !